# Why doesn't input button render in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

Why doesn't this render in IE9? (except in compatibility mode)

```
<input
    class='btn btn-default answerButton col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1'
    type='button'
    onclick='next(this)'
    value='" + titles[title] + "'
/>
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the quotes in your `value` attribute? Something like this: `&quot; + titles[title] + &quot;`

Comment: Are you building a string here? "value='" + titles[title] + "' />"

Comment: What do you mean by "render"? Are you suggesting no element is rendered at all on the screen, or it doesn't have the appearance you would expect? Are the bootstrap classes necessary?

Comment: It's not being loaded into the DOM. You think Bootstrap might be the reason? @JonathanSampson

Comment: I'm getting a string from the array titles @MarvinSmit

Comment: SOLVED: IE9 apparently cannot work with the input tags unless they're wrapped in form tags

Comment: @thehindutimes That doesn't sound correct; you should share more code so we can better assess the problem you're facing.

Comment: I put the input tags inside of a <form></form> and then it worked in IE9